# TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, python-3.9

I want to create a program to send an email with a discord bot but when i laucnh my program i have this error. My code to send an email works fine in a separate file but when i put in in my python discord bot program there are a problem
my programm :

`

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import os

import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv(dotenv_path="config")

default_intents = discord.Intents.default()
default_intents.members = True 
default_intents.message_content = True
default_intents.messages = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=":", intents=default_intents)

mail = ""
varBody = ""

@bot.event 
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot Ready !")
    await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Activity(type = discord.ActivityType.listening, name = "Cool Music !"))

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == "login":
        await message.channel.send("mail :")
        mail = await bot.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("Message : ")
        varBody = await bot.wait_for("message")
        await message.channel.send("finishing...")
        await email()

@bot.command()
async def email(, email, message):
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['Subject'] = 'Hi! I am Qiqi'
  msg['From'] = 'MAIL_ADDRESS'
  msg['To'] = mail
  password = "MAIL_PASSWORD"
  body = varBody
  msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.starttls()
  server.login(msg['From'], password)
  server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
  server.quit()



bot.run("TOKEN")


#terminal error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lussa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 409, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\lussa\Documents\BotdiscordPython\main.py", line 36, in on_message
    await email()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'context'
```

`

i have added "ctx" in the def email

but again the same error

Comment: `async def email(, email, message):` is a syntax error (that first comment). If it wasn't a syntax error, `await email()` wouldn't work because that function has required parameters.

Comment: Don't change presence in `on_ready`. Also you're missing a `process_commands` in that `on_message`, your commands won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I invite you to read the docs. All `bot.command()` need to have one mandatory parameter: context. It gives you all the info about the command used, but you can just ignore it if you don't need it.

Also you don't need to check the command message with `on_message()`, the command does it automatically.

Your code should work like this:

```py
@bot.command(name="login")
async def email(context):
  await context.send("mail :")
  mail = await bot.wait_for("message")
  await context.send("Message : ")
  varBody = await bot.wait_for("message")
  await context.send("finishing...")

  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['Subject'] = 'Hi! I am Qiqi'
  msg['From'] = 'MAIL_ADDRESS'
  msg['To'] = mail.content
  password = "MAIL_PASSWORD"
  body = varBody.content
  msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.starttls()
  server.login(msg['From'], password)
  server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
  server.quit()
```

Comment: it isn't work i have an other error message:

Comment: True. Sorry let me edit it.

Comment: i isn't work and i have an other error message : discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: email is a required argument that is missing.

Comment: Sorry it is work, i have just delete the email function in the def

Answer (score 0):

On your line `39` just remove the message parameter of the function and only pass `ctx`. It looks like you are not using any other parameters. Here's the updated line `email()` function:

```
@bot.command()
async def email(ctx, mail):
  msg = MIMEMultipart()
  msg['Subject'] = 'Hi! I am Qiqi'
  msg['From'] = 'MAIL_ADDRESS'
  msg['To'] = mail
  password = "MAIL_PASSWORD"
  body = varBody
  msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'html'))

  server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.starttls()
  server.login(msg['From'], password)
  server.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
  server.quit()
```